# Is there a point where one's reputation can increase perpetually without doing anything?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much reputation do you get while idle?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31265/how-much-reputation-do-you-get-while-idle)

Occasionally, I will get +10 rep for an answer that I gave maybe a year ago [presumably dug up from a search]. I haven't got too many “nice” answers (with 10 or more upvotes) but I was wondering whether if I have answered a huge number of questions with good answers, whether it's possible to reach the 200 rep daily cap just from old answers that people have dug up and upvoted, or whether this is already the case for people who have outstanding reputation already (50K or more).

I know about the Epic badge; but if you gave 50 amazing answers on 50 separate occasions it still might not guarantee you the rep-increasing perpetuation.

Comment: I get 600 rep per month with no significant further contributions to SO.  With a nearly 30k rep, then I'd expect to need 10 times that, or 300k in order to reach the daily rep cap most weekdays.

Answer (score 0):

[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) probably has something similar, as hes provided a really long list of answers. It is probably possible and has, or will, be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you suggesting that old questions eventual go to a state where they cannot be up voted any more.  I think that would be a good idea, or should maybe your points have a half life that decay over time to counter the situation you posed.